# How can I use sed to remove all characters before a specific symbol?

Tags: sed, regex

I have a text file and I need to get rid of all characters before the equals symbol in each line, for example:

The line:

```
File 1515 = foo.txt
```

needs to look like this:

```
=foo.txt
```

I tried this `sed` command:

```
sed s/=[^=]*^// everyone.pls
```

but it deletes all the characters after the equals symbol.

How can I delete the characters before `=`?

Answer (score 6):

To delete everything before the *first* equal sign:

```
sed 's/^[^=]*=/=/' everyone.pls
```

If the file `everyone.pls` looks like:

```
$ cat everyone.pls
File 1515 = foo.txt
File 1516 = foo=.xls
```

The the above command produces:

```
$ sed 's/^[^=]*=/=/' everyone.pls
= foo.txt
= foo=.xls
```

In the regex `^[^=]*=/`, the leading caret means that the regex has to match starting at the beginning of the line.  The expression `[^=]*=` matches every character up to and *including* the first equal sign.   Because we want the equal sign in the output, we need to substitute for all that an equal sign.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
sed 's/.*=/=/g' everyone.pls
```

to remove the characters before =

Comment: This will remove characters up until the _last_ equals. This may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: OP mentioned that he need to get rid off the entire information just before the = symbol

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other options, **these will all delete everything up to the *first* `=`**.

1. Perl

   ```
   perl -pe 's/.+?=/=/' everyone.pls
   ```

   The `-p` switch means "print every line" after applying the script passed with `-e`. 
   `s/pattern/replacement/` is the substitution operator and the regex means match any character up to the first `=`: `.` means any character and `+` means one or more and `?` makes the match non-greedy, it will stop at the  shortest matching string.
2. `awk`

   ```
   awk -F= '{$1="=";print;}' everyone.pls
   ```

   `awk` is a scripting language that automatically splits its input into fields and makes the fields available as `$1,$2...$N`. The `-F=` sets the field separator to `=` and `$1="="` will therefore replace the contents of the line before the first equals sign with an `=` and print the rest.
3. `grep`

   ```
   grep -o '=.*' everyone.pls
   ```

   The `-o` cause `grep` to only print the matched portion of the line. So, we search for the first `=` up until the end of the line.
4. `bash`

   ```
   while read line; do echo "=${line#*=}"; done < everyone.pls
   ```

   This is using a while loop to read each line, saving it in the variable `$line` and then using bash's string manipulation capabilities to modify it. The construct `${variable#pattern}` will remove the shortest match of `pattern` from the end of  `$variable`.
5. Needlessly complex

   ```
   cut -d= -f 2- everyone.pls | sed 's/^/=/'
   ```

   `cut` also works on fields, `-d=` makes it cut on `=`, `-f 2-` makes it print everything from the 2nd field to the end of the line and the `sed` substitution command adds an `=`.

Comment: In perl you can lookahead for the last `=` using `(?==)` and then you wouldn't have to replace the `=` back. I don't think `sed` supports that but `ssed` does.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, yes and lookarounds are often great but here they would just make the regex longer and harder to understand for non-experts, without adding any benefit. AFAIK, `sed` does not support PCREs, the best it can do is EREs with `-r` and they don't have lookarounds but thanks for mentioning `ssed`, did not know about it and it looks great!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*= */=/' YourFile
```

in your sample there i s space after `=` that you remove also, just 'adapt' other reply that don't take it into account but what you ask (until `=`).

Answer (score 1):

Almost right - just ordered your expressions backwards. What you want to do is replace all characters which are not `=` up to the first character which is `=` and any following spaces with a single `=` character.

Like this:

```
sed 's/[^=]*= */=/'
```

Your expression instead replaces all characters including and following the first `=` character on a line with a `=`.

And never mind the initial `^` leftmost anchor -; `sed` reads input left to right anyway, and so if it reads in an entire input line matching 0 `=` characters it will do nothing, but for all others it will only apply it's rule up to the leftmost `=` o a line.

Answer (score 0):

You might see the problem the other way round and try to match the part you want to keep:

```
sed 's:.*\(=.*$\):\1:' everyone.pls
```

i.e. match everything but surround the part you are interested in in brackets then you add the first group back with `\1`